# ElementHost - blank when reopening window

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I am working with a non WPF app so I can only create WPF user controls. My work around for this was to just create my windows as usercontrols and then I created a generic winform to host the wpf usercontrol (using ElementHost) to simulate a wpf window.

Everything works fine on my dev machine (WinXP VM) but on clients machines (VM and Physical, both Windows 7) the windows will open once and work fine. However, when he closes them and then reopens them, they are just blank white. The windows are being closed and disposed of after each close (same thing happened even if I left them in memory). Client has to close the application and start it back up again to see the windows again.

I've tried adding refresh calls and what not using the elementhost but nothing is working. Any ideas?! It happens on every window.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Not much to it, just ElementHost.Child = new WPFUserControl(); as I said, it has this issue with all user controls but only on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for posting this as an answer as I don't yet have the rights to just comment.  But I have some questions or possible directions to look into.

Have you tried seeing what's happening by attaching a debugger?  Is it still getting input events, or repaint events, or is it hung?  Is your WPF user control even loading when the window reopens?  Oh and make sure to break on first chance exceptions as well, perhaps it a WPF+CLR issue and it's not even getting a chance to load again.

Does Spy++ say anything about the child windows that might tell you what is going on?

Oh and does it happen only on his Win 7 box or does it repro elsewhere as well?

Another thing, what happens if you just create a simple user control and do the same thing?  Does it repro?

Does it repro if it's just content in the page rather than in a new window?

Try something simple like this article I just found while searching to see if anyone else has had this issue.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

Comment: Here's an old article on gotchas for interop between them.  Wonder if the dispose part they talk about might be the issue.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx

Comment: This page also mentions issues on Win 7. For some reason it worked for them when the WPF control was in a separate dll.
http://myramserialize.blogspot.com/2010/03/winformswpf-interop-elementhost-not.html

Comment: One more find before I just wait for your comments on any of this.  I found this with regards your windows perhaps this might be another thing to look into, it's about scrollbars, but reminded me in ways to your issue:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6f88715b-b9ca-4d4f-974b-97b334d26347/

Comment: If you read my question it states that it works on XP machines, just not Windows 7 machines. I'm using a user control and hosting it in an ElementHost control from a WinForm. It does it no matter what WPF usercontrol is used (there are many in my app). Happens weather it is disposed or left in memeory. I've already modified the OnPaint method and it didn't help. The WPF controls are already in separate DLLs as well. Didn't work in the same DLL either. Your second comment link has an interesting workaround that I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I hope it works.  If not if you have a simple repro and I have time I can take a look.  I'm leaving for somewhere at around 1pm PST and won't be back until late, but should be around most of the weekend.

Comment: it seems to work just fine on my Win7 VM so if it doesn't for him then oh well. Not much else I can do.

Comment: Excellent, so what exactly fixed the issue on your Win7 VM?

Comment: ElementHost.Child = WPFControl; var g = ElementHost.CreateGraphics(); g.Dispose(); in the OnLoad method of the form.

Comment: Seriously this answer needs and especially this comment above mine needs to get some serious attention... I just spend a good 5 hours trying to figure out what the hell is going on.. Thanks